# Small wireless temperature sensor recommendation

Tags: bluetooth, wireless, sensor, temperature

I am working on a human-care project using RPi. The second phase of project is in progress, and I need small **wireless** temperature sensor to be able to place on a human body. I've searched the internet, and couldn't really find any small-and-price-acceptable sensors for my need. [This](https://axzon.com/rfm3200-wireless-flexible-temperature-sensor/) one is the closest I saw (it's like a strip).

Also, I've found  [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01L9GV66U) on Amazon, and I wonder what's in the background ?

Do you have any suggestions or some lessons learned to share about this topic ? If there is no suitable wireless sensor, is there any bluetooth one that is practical for this usage ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without knowing more about your application it will be hard to recommend anything.  what range? runtime requirements? weight limits? Are you measuring body temperature or ambient temperature?

Comment: what are you asking here? ... `I wonder what's in the background ?`  ..... what does this mean? `price-acceptable`

Answer (score 2):

As a first suggestion: Suggest you [read this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/asking) then consider editing your question (after perhaps doing more of your own research) to cast it as a question maybe more about technology rather than one looking for a product recommendation.

It appears, at a glance, that the sensors you've looked at are [RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) **"tags"**. As a class of solutions to use in your project, RFID tags seem to meet your criteria: **wireless**, **small** and **inexpensive**. They are also typically "passive" which means they will not need to have a battery. Further research for RFID solutions may lead to more and better choices than Amazon - which offers only what they have for sale!

While you haven't mentioned this in your question, you should also research RFID **readers**. There are add-on kits ([for example](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/rc522-rfid-tag-read-raspberry-pi/)) available from several vendors that will enable the RPi to read a passive RFID tag.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a infrared camera,but you shall calibrate and filter colors, [this the cheap camera](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1567) and this article wikipedia [thermal camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermographic_camera), ofcourse is wireless , but require scan directly object , this [article](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/publiclab/infragram-the-infrared-photography-project) that use raspberry pi and camera

Comment: So this real [thermo camera](https://learn.adafruit.com/thermal-camera-with-display)